# Is it planned to use SPIP as a basis CMS for CIVICRM?

Tags: api, developer

SPIP is a multilingual open-source CMS created in 2001, and a lot of non-profit use it as their website tool in France and other countries. Is it planned, or do you heard about some people willing to use civicrm together with SPIP ?
Many thanks in advance,
Cyril

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, it seems that SPIP is a CMS and not a CRM.  While there are no plans for native integration between CiviCRM and other CMSes beyond the four currently supported, many organizations still integrate CiviCRM with their existing CMS.  Simple integration options include [remote profile submissions using snippets](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#standalone-forms-with-profiles).  You can also use [remoteform](https://civicrm.org/blog/jamie/display-civicrm-forms-on-any-web-site-anywhere), which also works with contribution pages.

If you wanted a deeper integration, you could use [CiviMRF](https://github.com/CiviMRF/documentation), but that would take development work.

Comment: Thank you Jon.
Is there a place where I can understand why CiviCRM is built **over** a standard CMS such as Drupal or Wordpress, and how I could imagine to participate to the development of an integration with SPIP ?

Comment: @CyrilMarion The decision to integrate over a CMS was made back in the beginning, and I believe was mainly because a) it was a selling point to offer deeper integration, b) it meant not having to manage user sessions etc.  However, many people run CiviCRM "standalone" with just a barebones Drupal or WP install with no other plugins.  I believe the CiviCRM core team has ruled out supporting more CMSes because of the testing/maintenance overhead of supporting them.